# Bash script to select files to execute

Tags: bash

I have been studying bash recently.

I need a bash code that displays a list of files in the current directory and prompts for which file to execute.

If the user enters a valid choice, then the executable file selection should be invoked.

Comment: Please show some effort.  If you've been studying bash, then you must have at least some progress toward a solution?

Comment: Well, there's their previous question: [select files from a set](http://superuser.com/questions/358294/select-files-from-a-set).

Comment: -1 Question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Neither did the previous one, 5 hours prior.  Vote to close.  Again.  @user105716, please come back when you get stuck, not when you get started.

Answer (score 2):

To get you started, look up these constructs in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

```
select file in *

if [[ -x "$file" ]]

exec "$file"
```

Comment: heh, looks a little like SQL, I thought you were kidding for a moment, i'll have to study bash a bit again too!